# start-stop-daemon won't start my Python script as service

Tags: sysvinit, start-stop-daemon

I am trying to run Google AppEngine on my Debian machine, I created a file `init.d/gae`:

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Initialize variables
#

name=gae
user=$name

pid=/var/run/$name.pid
prog="python /opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 --admin_host=0.0.0.0 --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi /var/www"


case "${1}" in
   start)
      echo "Starting...Google App Engine"
      start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --background --oknodo --user "$user" --name "$name" --pidfile "$pid" --startas "$prog" 

      ;;

   stop)
      echo "Stopping...Google App Engine"

      ;;

   restart)
      ${0} stop
      sleep 1
      ${0} start
      ;;

   *)
      echo "Usage: ${0} {start|stop|restart}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac

exit 0

# End scriptname
```

I am testing the script by manually invoking, and the script runs but not as a daemon or at least it doesn't detach from terminal. I am expecting/looking for similar functionality to Apache.

**What switch am I missing?**

---

**EDIT**

I should note that no PID file is being written or created despite the switch indicating it should be created

Comment: Does User gae have opermission to write to `/var/run`?

Comment: You don't have a `#!` definition defined. I think that will cause an issue. What do you want this to run as? `bash`, `sh`, `ksh`? Putting a `#!/bin/bash` will tell the system which shell to run this as.

Comment: The `prog=python /opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py...` line is missing quotes, causing it to get started there, not inside the `start-stop-daemon` code.

Comment: It's not related to your answer : your script is not standard, add LSB header to head of your script.

Comment: Where is `python` located and is that in the PATH when the `init.d` files are started.

Comment: If you are more familiar with python why not write your init.d script in python? :)

Comment: Adding the quotes seems to allow the start-stop-daemon to work as I am now getting a gae.pid file created but the process seems to terminate immediately?!? Any ideas why?

Comment: @Anthon how do I check to see if the paths are available or correct? How would I add the Python path (what is the path even)? I've been reading all morning and this sounds likely to be the candidate to finally get this working :)

Comment: @Alex.Barylski To check the path the script is using I would add a line `echo $PATH > /var/tmp/path.tmp` restart the service and see what the path is. In your case I would just do `type python` from the commandline and hardcode the full path in the init.d instead of just `python`

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin...no mention of python...ugh why does Python invoke when I call it "python" from CLI? What path do I use?

Comment: /usr/bin/python XYZ did not work either...ugh any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems I can see:

> prog=python /opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 --admin_host=0.0.0.0 --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi /var/www

Will start `/opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py` with `prog=python` in the environment.  This is before your `start` block, so `start-stop-daemon` isn't even getting involved.

The quick fix is to quote the entire assignment like this:

> prog='python /opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 --admin_host=0.0.0.0 --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi /var/www'

But a better fix is to use the style from `/etc/init.d/skeleton`, and do

```
DAEMON='python /opt/google/appengine/dev_appserver.py'
DAEMON_ARGS='--host=0.0.0.0 --admin_host=0.0.0.0 --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi /var/www'
```

The second problem is that you're wrongly quoting `$prog`.

> start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --background --oknodo --user "$user" --name "$name" --pidfile "$pid" --startas "$prog"

tells `start-stop-daemon` to try to start a program called `python /opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 --admin_host=0.0.0.0 --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi /var/www`.

But clearly there is no program called that.  You want to start `python` with arguments.  Removing the double quotes there is the quick fix, but a better one, again following `/etc/init.d/skeleton`, would be

> start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $CHUID --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS

Comment: Damn, was just about to post this :-). Your final command though is missing `--background`, `--make-pidfile`, and `--oknodo`. Any particular reason?

Comment: Well, I identified the problem 23 hours ago, so figured I might as well get the points. ;)

Comment: I was just copying the flags from the skeleton file.  You're right that in this case it looks like `--background` and friends can be re-added.

Comment: I did end up quoting the prog value (I edited original post) and that didn't work. If it was the double quotes causing this issue...I will carp my pants -- late though so I will test first thing tomorrow.

Comment: DAEMON_ARGS made all the difference...jeepers crepes...thank you so much...I tried so many combinations...an entire day troubleshooting python, start-stop-daemon, etc...and the solution was a simple syntactical fix...man I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480897/5132 `/etc/init.d/skeleton` has been superseded.

Answer (score 0):

For the life of me I could not figure out why start-stop-daemon was not working...I am running Debian 7.6 wheezy and I can only assume the feature has been disabled.

I change the like to use /dev/null and the & and voila -- sciprt starts and stays running as expected...I stole the code from mysql:

```
$prog > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I would be very interested if someone could explain why this works and the original solution does not...in anycase I figured I would share my experience in hopes of:

1. Saving someone else the headache of mucking around with the solution
2. Prompting someone to step up and explain how to get this working as I originally wanted :)

EDIT | Here are the two lines of interest now

```
prog='/usr/bin/python /opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 --admin_host=0.0.0.0 --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi /var/www'

start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --background --oknodo --user $user --name $name --pidfile $pid --exec $prog
```

Comment: I think it's because you removed the quotes from `"$prog"`.  Remove the `>/dev/null 2>&1 &` part and see what happens.

Comment: OK I edited the answer I provided with the changes I made and now i'm getting an error (start-stop-daemon: unrecognized option '--host=0.0.0.0'

Comment: You need the `--` like in `$DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS`.